# Why does the debugger's breakpoint condition allow an assignment-statement as bool-condition?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

This is very dangerous so I wonder why it's allowed. Since I often need to switch between VB.NET and C# I sometimes add breakpoint-conditions like following:

```
foo = "bah"
```

I want to stop if the `string` variable `foo` is `"bah`, so the correct way was to use `foo == "bah"` instead of `foo = "bah"`.

But it "works". You don't get any warnings or errors at compile- or runtime. But actually this *modifies* the variable `foo`, it makes it always `"bah"` even if it had a different value. Since that happens silently (the breakpoint never gets hit) it is incredibly dangerous.

Why is it allowed? Where is my error in reasoning (apart from confusing the C# and VB.NET syntax)? In C# (as opposed to VB.NET) an [assignment statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2wkh0tk(v=vs.90).aspx) returns the value that was assigned, so not a `bool`, but a `string` in this case. But a breakpoint condition has to be a `bool` if you check the box  *"Is True"*.

Here is a little sample "program" and  screenshots from my (german) IDE:

```
static void Main()
{
    string foo = "foo";
    // breakpoint with assignment(foo = "bah") instead of comparison(foo == "bah"):
    Console.WriteLine(foo);  // bah, variable is changed from the breakpoint window
}
```

The breakpoint-condition dialog:

[image]

The code as image including the breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: Good question.  That definitely sounds like a bug.

Comment: Definitely doesn't seem to match the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.debug.breakpt.condition);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true): "The breakpoint is skipped only if the condition is valid and evaluates to false"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, at runtime the debugger normally stops at the breakpoint if it's invalid and points that out. But not in case of an assignment. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: That's dangerous but it can definitely be useful in some debugging scenarios, to test variations without recompiling. Adding this one to my toolbox :)

Comment: @KooKiz: you can always use the quick-watch window of the debugger to change variables if you want. But the breakpoint-condition dialog should not modify the variables in my opinion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah but quickwatch forces to break every time you want to change the value, which can be bothersome in some situations (inside of a loop for instance). It'd be best if the debugger team fixed this behavior, but I definitely plan on taking advantage of it in the meantime

Comment: @KooKiz: don't forget to remove the breakpoint if you "go live". Actually my code was running in a windows-service which was importing during night. Now i have  thousands of incorrect records in the database.

Comment: Trying this in VS 2013 (I know your question is tagged 2010) gets an error including "The breakpoint condition must evaluate to a boolean operation" - so maybe already fixed.

Comment: In my case I tested on VS 2012 and it works

Comment: @KooKiz: so you  can you confirm this _bug_ in VS 2012?

Comment: I confirm the bug is present in VS2012 and VS2008. Unfortunately I don't have a VS2013 on that computer, but @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's conclusion seems likely

Comment: I like this question. Still, sorry to say, but this seems a bug, and can't be reasonably be answered without knowledge of the system behind it, and if it can be answered, where is the use?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: no problem, the use is that i (and others) now know that this is a bug and not caused by some language- or compiler-features or a special visual studio setting. So obviously you have to remember this and you can't disable this behaviour. Bad news are sometimes also helpful ;) But maybe this needs to be closed because the bugis not even be documented on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/), is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: True, but the answer is 'this is a bug' (I am happy to answer that ;) ), but I doubt the usefulness of such an answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:  i've edited my comment later, yes, maybe this needs to be closed since it cannot be answered in a helpful way. If someone finds documentation of this bug or under "fixed issues" in a Visual Studio update -history, that would be a good answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Can't find it either. It has been changed, so they must have found it... Maybe a MS dev found it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an automatic consequence of C# syntax, common in the curly-braces language group.  An assignment is also an expression, its result is the value of the right-hand side operand.  The debugger does not object either to expressions having side-effects, nor would it be simple at all to suppress them.  It could be blamed for not checking that the expression has a *bool* result, the debugger however does not have a full-blown C# language parser.  This might well be fixed in VS2015 thanks to the Roslyn project. [Note: see addendum at the bottom].

Also the core reason that the curly-brace languages need a separate operator for equality, == vs =.  Which in itself must be responsible for a billion dollar worth of bugs, every C programmer makes that mistake at least once.

VB.NET is different, assignment is a statement and the `=` token is valid for both assignment and comparison.  You can tell from the debugger, it picks the equality operator instead and doesn't modify the variable.

Do keep in mind that this is actually useful.  It lets you temporarily work around a bug, forcing the variable value and allowing you to continue debugging and focus on another problem.  Or create a test condition.  That's pretty useful.  In a previous life-time, I wrote a compiler and debugger and implemented "trace points".  Discovered the same scenario by accident and left it in place.  It ran in a host that relied heavily on state machines, overriding the state variable while debugging was incredibly useful.  The accident, no, not so useful :)

---

A note about what other SO users are observing, it depends on the debugging engine that you use.  The relevant option in VS2013 is Tools + Options, Debugging, General, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  Same option exists in VS2012, it had a slightly different name (don't remember).  When ticked you get an older debugging engine, one that is still compatible with C++/CLI.  Same one as used in VS2010.

So that's a workaround for VS2013, untick the option to get the debugger to check that the expression produces a bool result.  You get some more goodies with that new debugging engine, like seeing method return values and Edit+Continue support for 64-bit processes.

Comment: "This might well be fixed in VS2015" - it's fixed in VS2013 according to the comments

Comment: Thanks. But as Damien_The_Unbeliever [has pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366325/why-does-the-debuggers-breakpoint-condition-allow-an-assignment-statement-as-bo/28368611#comment45074312_28366325) in his comment this seems to be already fixed in VS 2013, isn't it?

Comment: I don't have this option in VS 2010, isn't it new in 2012? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Then you automatically have the old debugging engine of course.

Answer (score 1):

I can disagree about buggy nature of this behavior. Few examples where for debugging purposes in my life if was useful:
1. Other thread modifies something in your code.
2. Other service updated value in db
So I suppose for cases of synchronization it can be useful feature, but I agree that it can cause problems

Comment: But why should a breakpoint-condition window be responsible for changing variables?  It's sole purpose is to define the breakpoint condition and not to modify my program. You can use the other debugger windows like the quick watch window to modify variables. So even if it was helpful for you (and Hans Passant), it's a great source of danger of accidental changes which won't be recognized.

Comment: Agree with you. I just proposed something that I call bugs usage

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019, variable assignment expressions in Breakpoint conditions no longer work.

The expression will be evaluated for value, but side effects such as variable assignment are discarded.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/715716/variables-cannot-be-assigned-in-breakpoint-conditi.html