# Using/abusing a conditional breakpoint to manipulate a value

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

For a temporary workaround, I have to set User.ID to 0 in a certain line. My usual approach for similar cases is to set a breakpoint at the corresponding line and use the watch to manipulate the value:

```
User.ID = 0
```

In an attempt to streamline this by automatically setting the value, I came up with a conditional breakpoint with this condition:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(User.ID = 0)
```

Since this expression evaluates to false, the code execution does not stop and as a side effect User.ID would be set to 0. As it turns out, this side effect does not happen. I am sure that this is by design. *The exact same code works as expected in the watch, though.* My questions:

- How does Visual Studio handle side effects in conditional
  breakpoints and is there maybe some official documentation for that?
- Can Visual Studio be tricked to allow this side effect?
- Is there an alternative way to reach the desired behaviour (i. e. setting a variable automatically at a certain point while debugging)?

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question seems to be related: [Why does the debugger's breakpoint condition allow an assignment-statement as bool-condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366325/why-does-the-debuggers-breakpoint-condition-allow-an-assignment-statement-as-bo)

It seems that this bug(in my opinion the debugger should not allow side effects from a breakpoint condition) was fixed in VS2013.

You have to change the setting if you want that side-effect:

- Tools + Options
- Debugging
- General
  --> "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox

Tick that and you should get the old behaviour. I'm on 2010 so i cannot test it. But  i trust [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28368611/284240) in this.

Comment: As I recall, though "fixed" for conditional breakpoints in VS2013, you can still have side-effects in the output statement of a "when-hit" breakpoint without changing the debugging settings.

Comment: @Iridium: Thanks, it worked. I actually looked first into the "when hit"-breakpoint, but then dismissed it, because I didn't want the overhead of printing a message. I later concluded, that it would not work in "when-hit"-breakpoints, if it does not work in a conditional breakpoint, because there should be the same reasoning behind restricting side effects.